# How to find proftpd compile options Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, proftpd

I need to upgrade proftpd that is running on my Ubuntu 14.04 server.
Since I want to keep all configfiles as they are I thought the best option would be to compile a newer version 1.3.5b and just copy in the binary to replace the current running.
Would work fine in theory but I am running into issues because I probably do not have the right configure options.
Is there a way to see the configure / compile options for the proftpd package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Castaglia's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317013/86440) is easier to use with ProFTPd, and works on any system.

As a more general solution for Debian packages (including Ubuntu), you can find the configure options in the [`debian/rules` file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/proftpd-dfsg/trusty-proposed/view/head:/debian/rules) (that link takes you directly to the version used in 14.04):

```
CONF_ARGS := --prefix=/usr \
         --with-includes=$(shell pg_config --includedir):$(shell mysql_config --include|sed -e 's/-I//') \
         --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc/$(NAME) --localstatedir=/var/run --libexecdir=/usr/lib/$(NAME) \
         --enable-sendfile --enable-facl --enable-dso --enable-autoshadow --enable-ctrls --with-modules=mod_readme \
         --enable-ipv6 --enable-nls --enable-memcache --with-lastlog=/var/log/lastlog --enable-pcre $(DEVELOPT)
```

To find this yourself, go to the [Launchpad page for `proftpd-dfsg`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/proftpd-dfsg), click on "Code" at the top of the screen, then on the branch for the release you're interested in, then on "Browse the code". Once you're there you can work your way down to `debian/rules`.

Comment: Another way is to use `proftpd -V`; each ProFTPD binary contains its own compile time options recorded.  This works for every platform, not just Debian.

Comment: Well, that was even easier :) I should have seen it myself. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenKitt done -- thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: @Castaglia and upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

Another cross-platform way to find the compile-time options for your ProFTPD installation is to use ProFTPD `-V` command-line option:

```
$ ./proftpd -V
```

Each `proftpd` executable contains its own compile-time options recorded, for just such situations.